# Emulate drawing in UIAutomation

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have an application that allows the user to write into an area using a drawing function and then save the image. Is there a way to emulate this with UIAutomation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use build-in function dragFromToForDuration(from, to, timeout). Getting the object properties line origin.x and origin.y and size.width and size.height you will be able to set from and to coordinates for your drawing. You can even try to draw something awesome :)

This code will draw a line for 3 seconds from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of your drawing Area (at least I hope it will). You can change timeout parameter to draw faster or slower.

```
var drawingAreaObject = ...mainWindow().<yourObject>;

var drawingAreaObjectRect = drawingAreaObject.rect();

var xBeginDrawPoint = drawingAreaObjectRect.origin.x + 1;
var yBeginDrawPoint = drawingAreaObjectRect.origin.y + 1;

var xEndDrawPoint = drawingAreaObjectRect.origin.x + drawingAreaObjectRect.size.width - 1;
var yEndDrawPoint = drawingAreaObjectRect.origin.y + drawingAreaObjectRect.size.height - 1;

UIATarget.localTarget().dragFromToForDuration({x:xBeginDrawPoint, y:yBeginDrawPoint}, {x:xEndDrawPoint, y:yEndDrawPoint}, 3);
```

You can also try the flickInsideWithOptions (I'm not sure about this one but theoretically it is possible) or tapWithOptions() to draw a point.
Unfortunately you will be able to draw only lines using this functions.